# Minecraft exit code 134

Tags: java, minecraft

So just starting the other day for some reason when I click play on the Minecraft launcher it will close and re-open so I checked my development code and get this error:

```
      Game ended with bad state (exit code 134)
```

So I looked it up and it appears as if I have to update my Java. I currently use Java open JDK7 runtime. Since I didn't know how to update my Java I have tried re-installing my 
.Minecraft client and Java, I still got the same error. I have Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I would like to know how I would go about updating my Java.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a terminal and typing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove java
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Now, to ensure you have the latest java, in the terminal type:

```
java -version
```

It should pull up something to this effect:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Now, locate your Minecraft.jar file, right-click it, go to "Properties," then the "Permissions" tab, and **MAKE SURE THE "MARKED AS EXECUTABLE" BOX IS CHECKED!**, then go to the "Open With" tab and search for Oracle Java 7 Runtime and select "Set as default."

Now close the Properties window, right-click Minecraft.jar and make sure the top line is "Open With Oracle Java 7 Runtime."

Hope this helps!  ^-^

Comment: `java` is not a package name. It may be `openjdk-jre7` or similar.

Comment: So downloading oracle went well but this time when I clcik play on the launcher the minecraft window appears but it acts as another desktop or something and doesnt display the normal Mojang logo then a bit later it gave me the same exit code. I know that oracle worked because it said it when launching in the beginning.

Comment: Here is where you can see the full launcher development consle: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6736557/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the latest java (version 7 update 45) from [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/)?  Unless your java isn't the most up-to-date version, I don't know what the problem would be.

Comment: this is what I get when I do java -version:                            java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)